# My host switched to CF11 and my CF web service no longer returns elements in its object

Tags: web-services, coldfusion, cfc

I have a web service that was working in CF9 for several years. It returns an object which is instantiated with code like this:

```
<cfset results.approved="initial">
<cfset results.total_charged = "0">
<cfset results.charge_error = "">
<cfset results.renewed_until = "">
<cfset results.reason="">
<cfset results.errors=arrayNew(2)>
```

However, since the server upgraded to CF11, I no longer see any of the data elements in that object. When I do a cfdump of the returned object, I see only methods - like this:

ClassName    DefaultNamespace.Join_results

Methods      (then a list of methods, but no elements)

What do I need to do so that it starts returning the data again?

If I can't solve that, I would like to figure out how debug the code, but I can't because I can only run the web service with a harness, and the harness is not getting any data back. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: The results object is instantiated like this     
<cfobject type="component" component="join_results"  name="results">

Comment: Where in your cfc is that code?

Answer (score 3):

In versions of ColdFusion since 10, the default version of AXIS used to publish web services is version 2. The fix to get your web service working should be as simple as adding the following to your remote CFC

```
<cfcomponent wsversion="1">
```

Or, in script

```
component wsversion="1"{
    ...code here ...
}
```